# Are nested sub-selects needed in sql server query to select max of 1 field and min of another?

Tags: sql-server, nested, subquery

I need to select records that contain the maximum value of one field (queryresolutiondate) in a table, then within that subset, I need to select just the records that contain the minimum value of another field (queryestablishdate).  I have tried to select the min and max in a single sub-select, but unfortunately, the absolute min and max do not always occur in the same record, so no records are returned.

THe following query works, but this code is part of a much larger query that returns approx 45 columns, and I would prefer not to group 44 columns:

```
select
q.[SourceCustomerId],
q.[SourceProductCode],
q.[SourceProductIssueNum],
min (q.[QueryEstablishDate]),
q.[SourceQueryCode],
q.[SourceQueryStatus],
q.[QueryResolutionDate]

from [dbo]..[dQueryAll] q with (nolock) 

inner join (select [SourceCustomerId], [SourceProductCode], [SourceProductIssueNum],   [SourceQueryCode], 
 max([QueryResolutionDate]) as maxQueryResolutionDate
from [dbo]..[dQueryAll] with (nolock) 
where [SourceQueryCode] = 311
group by [sourceCustomerId], [SourceProductCode], [SourceProductIssueNum], [SourceQueryCode]) qg 
on (qg.[SourceCustomerId] = q.[SourceCustomerId] and qg.[SourceProductCode] = q.[SourceProductCode]
 and qg.[SourceProductIssueNum] = q.[SourceProductIssueNum] 
 and qg.maxQueryResolutionDate = q.[QueryResolutionDate])

group by
q.[SourceCustomerId],
q.[SourceProductCode],
q.[SourceProductIssueNum],
q.[SourceQueryCode],
q.[SourceQueryStatus],
q.[QueryResolutionDate]
```

I wondered if I could create another sub-select within the subselect above to select the min establish date from the rocrds that contained the max resloution date.  If this is possible, I would like some help

I have an example of the data in the table that I have pasted into Excel, but cannot find how to load it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest selects, however if there is a good relevant index, grouping by a large number columns should not be a performance problem.

As to nesting, just write the inner sub query, then write the outer one if it were running ona flat table. the replace the flat subquery with the inner sub query.

HTH

Comment: I tried the following, but it still does not work...Any suggestions?

Comment: What does the inner subquery return? Why do you want the (outside = 331) the data is already limited by the inside = 331. Actually I've seen situations where this confuses the optimiser and causes the query execution to become much longer (it was useful in SQL7 days but not anymore) Its difficult to comment without some test data, can you post a schema and some insert statements?

Comment: I have test data in an Excel file, but don't know how to post it here

Comment: I also found that I need to add another selection criteria that makes this more complicated...when source query status = 1, I want the minimum resoltion date (which will always be 1/1/1900 and the minimum establish date.  However, for all other source query codes, I still want the original criteria

Comment: I solved the most recent problem and ended up just keeping the groupings.  Thanks for your assistance.  Should I flag the question as answered?

Comment: Quite often its just thinking how to explain the problem which is the bigest part of solving it. If the resposes help you solve the problem, then it may help others and so the answer would be yes.